# Add horizontal Scrolling

Tags: editor, sublimetext2

I am trying to make it so when I hold Alt and scroll the mouse wheel the editor scrolls to the right or left.

I have tried adding this to the (Windows).sublime-mousemap file.

```
{ "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["alt"], "command": "scroll_width", "args": {"amount": 30 } },
{ "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["alt"],  "command": "scroll_width", "args": {"amount": -30 } },
```

But it will not pick up this command. I am new to sublime so I think I might have the syntax wrong or missed something out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have found elsewhere I don't think this is natively supported so I installed a package to add this command. For anyone else that is completely new here is a step by step idiots guide.

Install wbond package manager (This has a lot of functionality other than just installing packages like I will do)
https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

You need to run the code on this page (Pick Sublime2 or 3 depending on which you have)
To open up the text console within Sublime you need to press 3 keys on windows Crtl + and ' Make sure you have the third which is a single quote! It took me a few looks to see if it was dirt on my screen or a quote!

A small text field opens at the bottom of sublime. Copy and past the command from wbonds installation instructions and press enter.

Then press CTRL P
search for Horizontal Scroll by TheOnlyRew
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Horizontal%20Scroll

Click on that option and then add this code to your windows mouse map file

```
{ "button": "scroll_up", "modifiers": ["alt"], "command": "scroll_width", "args": {"amount": 30 } },
{ "button": "scroll_down", "modifiers": ["alt"],  "command": "scroll_width", "args": {"amount": -30 } },
```

If adding this at the end of a file remove the last comma.

NOTE: Current Issue that I have encountered. This works, the only caveat is that after a horizontal scroll on my laptops trackpad I cannot then do a vertical scroll! I have to click or highlight somewhere in the document.